# PHP not triggering Fatal Error when memory_limit reached

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I have basic page where i am trying to have `Fatal Error, Out of memory` message show, however nothing happens script works no errors, PHP 7.1.9 no suhosin.

```
ini_set("memory_limit", 100); //100 bytes.
echo "Memory Limit Bytes " . ini_get("memory_limit") . PHP_EOL;
echo "Script peak memory usage " . memory_get_peak_usage() . PHP_EOL;
```

Output no Fatal Error.

```
Memory Limit Bytes 100
Script peak memory usage 386960
The End
```

Comment: try to add on the top ot that page an :  ini_set('memory_limit, "128M");

Answer (score 2):

You are tapping into a very troublesome area of PHP. The problem is, as soon as your PHP process runs out of memory it's game over. An exception isn't thrown because the fatal error triggers script termination.

According to my experience, your best bet here is to use register_shutdown_function() to register a callback that will check error_get_last() and handle the offending code muted by the @ (shut up) operator, or ini_set('display_errors', false).

If you need to execute important clean-up code when this error happens, registering a shutdown function is not enough. One approach is to allocate some emergency memory somewhere you can free when your PHP process went sideways.

```
<?php 
ini_set("memory_limit", 400000); //100 bytes
ini_set('display_errors', false);
error_reporting(-1);

echo("start");
echo "Memory Limit Bytes " . ini_get("memory_limit") . PHP_EOL;
echo "Script peak memory usage " . memory_get_peak_usage() . PHP_EOL;

// This storage is freed on error (case of allowed memory exhausted)
$memory = str_repeat('*', 100000);
echo("2");
set_error_handler(function($code, $string, $file, $line){
        throw new ErrorException($string, null, $code, $file, $line);
    });

register_shutdown_function(function(){
    global $memory;
    $memory = null;
    $error = error_get_last();
    if(null !== $error)
    {
        echo 'Caught at shutdown';
    }
});

try
{
    $a = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
        $a .= '1';
    }
    echo("done");
}
catch(\Exception $exception)
{
    echo 'Caught in try/catch';
}
?>
```

Check out this [article](https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die) which discusses PHP's memory handling (among other things).